# is there any difference of solving the probability of winning one prize and winning exactly 1 prize

Tags: probability

The question is: I bought 2 raffle tickets for a fundraiser.  3 tickets are drawn out of 100 for 3 different prizes.  what is the probability for me winning exactly 1 prize?
a) 5.94%  b) 1.96%   c) 5.88%   d) 94.06%

my working was: 2/100 x 98/99 x 3 = 5.94%, but it is wrong.

I need help to figure out why, and how to work out this type of probability questions.
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ir is always safer to work out such problems (choosing without replacement) using combinations

One of your tickets got a prize, the other did *not*,

Thus $\boxed{\dfrac{\binom31\binom{97}1}{\binom{100}2}= 5.88\%}$

If you want to do it by direct multiplication, you need to do

$\dfrac3{100}\dfrac{97}{99}*2 = 5.88\%$

Why I suggest the first approach is that people often forget the multiplier at the end

Comment: Thanks lot.  is there a formula for calculating this type of probability questions?

Comment: Of course, I recommend the first formula which I am putting in a block. Are you having any doubt about its logic ?

Comment: I do not understand the first formula as I have not gotten that far in my studies. I do understand the second formula more though, with direct multiplication. Is there some sort of formula for that?

Comment: Well, then use direct multiplication, but remember that you have to multiply by $2$ because the prize could be won by either the first or second ticket. Regarding the first formula it is a standard formula for a **hypergeometric distribution** (which deald with selection without replacement). Soon you should be learning about it, then match what you learn with the formula here.

Comment: By the way, "winning one prize" is not a mathematically precise statement. It should either state "winning *exactly* one prize" or "winning *at least* one prize", or "winning *at most* one prize

Comment: how do you calculate 'winning at most one prize"? is that same as 'winning at least one prize?

Comment: At most means 0 or 1, at least means 1 or more

Comment: Is the answer clear ?